# creating dynamic url with mongodb in ejs file

Tags: javascript, mongodb, dynamic, express

I'm trying to figure out how I can get a dynamic link in my ejs file using mongodb records, like a topic id.

I'm very new with the use of node.js, express, mongo and ejs files.
So I don't really know how I can make this happen.

here is some code that is related to this part of the app.

what I've already tried in the index.ejs:

```
<ul>
                       <% for(var i = 0; i < topic.length; i++) {%>
                          <li>
                            <div class="post animated fadeInLeft">
                               <div class="wrap-ut pull-left">
                                   <div class="userinfo pull-left">
                                      <div class="avatar">
                                         <img src="images/avatar.jpg" alt="default avatar" />
                                         <p class="moderator"> <%= topic[i].fbUsername %> </p>
                                      </div>
                                   </div>
                               <div class="posttext pull-left">
                                   <h2 class="topictitle"><a href="/topicdetail/:_id"> <%= topic[i].topicTitle %>  </a></h2>
                           </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </div>
                  </li>
                  <% } %>
                </ul>
```

The index.js

```
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  Topic.find({}).exec(function(err, topic)
  {
    if(err){

      console.log('There ware no topics');
      return next(err)
    }
    else
  {
    console.log('Whoop whoop there are some topics');


    res.render('index', { topic: topic } );

    console.log("Logging data: " + topic);
    console.log("Loggin data title out db: " + topic.topicTitle);
    console.log("Loggin data desc out db: " + topic.topicDescription);
    console.log("Loggin data date out db: " + topic.topicDateCreated);
  }
  });

});


module.exports = router;
```

Do I have to add a get method or a post method somewhere in the app.js file?

Comment: Can't you simply append the _id to the url? `<a href="/topicdetail/<%= topic[i]._id %>" > <%= topic[i].topicTitle %>  </a>`

Comment: I've tried that , but that doesn't work. If I click the link it gives this as url: http://localhost:3001/topicdetail/topic[i]._id%20%.